# How to replace a [] in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am writing a bash script for installing django with postgresql database automatically. Now , I want to replace database name by command ,since it is using sqlite3 database file path.

I wrote this command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/ALLOWED_HOSTS = []/ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']/g"  $project_name/settings.py
```

But it shows me this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command

How to change this , please help me.

Comment: `"s/ALLOWED_HOSTS = \[\]/ALLOWED_HOSTS = \['*'\]/g"`

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show us an example of the input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single-quotes as below:-

```
sed -i "s/ALLOWED_HOSTS = \[\]/ALLOWED_HOSTS = \['*'\]/g" file
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the quotes would need to be escaped here.

Comment: @TomFenech: Fixed it thanks!

Comment: The `[` and `]` in the replacement string don't need to be escaped either. Neither does the `]` in the search string (but I can see why people would do that).

Comment: @Inian Thanks for solving it.

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan: Happy to help! But please do a bit of search in the community before posting new questions. Thanks!